# Relationships between one- and two-norms

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I think this is quite a basic question but I'm struggling with it. Suppose $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n$ are a set of finite-dimensional vectors and $a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n)$ are $n$-dimensional vectors of scalars. In the [solution](http://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/archive/116_fall_03/solutions/solns1.pdf) to a problem, we have:

> \begin{align}\max_i ||x_i|| \cdot  \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i - b_i| &= \max_i
>  ||x_i|| \cdot ||a-b||_1\\& \leq \sqrt{n}\max_i ||x_i|| \cdot ||a-b||_2
>  \end{align}

Could someone please explain the last inequality? I understand that $||a-b||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i-b_i|^2}$ and so $\sqrt{n} ||a-b||_2 = \sqrt{n\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i-b_i|^2}$ but wasn't sure how to show that $\sqrt{n\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i-b_i|^2} \geq \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i - b_i|$.

Comment: I apologize. I'm afraid I can't edit it, but if there is a moderator who can, I'd appreciate it if they correct it.

Update: I just updated the title. Thanks.

Comment: This is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\sum_i u_i v_i \le \sqrt{\left(\sum_i u_i^2\right) \left(\sum_i v_i^2\right)}$$
applied with $u_i = |a_i - b_i|$ and $v_i = 1$.